# Strange problems when using requests and multiprocessing

Tags: python, linux, multiprocessing, kill, python-requests

Please check this python code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import requests
import multiprocessing
from time import sleep, time
from requests import async

def do_req():
    r = requests.get("http://w3c.org/")

def do_sth():    
    while True:
        sleep(10)

if __name__ == '__main__':        
    do_req()
    multiprocessing.Process( target=do_sth, args=() ).start()
```

When I press Ctrl-C (wait 2sec after run - let Process run), it doesn't stop. When I change the import order to:

```
from requests import async
from time import sleep, time
```

it stops after Ctrl-C. Why it doesn't stop/kill in first example?

It's a bug or a feature?

Notes:

- Yes I know, that I didn't use async in this code, this is just stripped down code. In real code I use it. I did it to simplify my question.
- After pressing Ctrl-C there is a new (child) process running.  Why?
- `multiprocessing.__version__ == 0.70a1`, `requests.__version__ == 0.11.2`, `gevent.__version__ == 0.13.7`

Comment: maybe you overwrite some module or function names (time?). Try to stop using "from .. import .." and use fully qualified names like "time.time()", maybe this solves your problem (didn't try it myself)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Requests async module uses gevent. If you look at the source code of gevent you will see that it [monkey patches](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monkey_patch) many of Python's standard library functions, including sleep:

request.async module during import executes:

```
    from gevent import monkey as curious_george
    # Monkey-patch.
    curious_george.patch_all(thread=False, select=False)
```

Looking at the monkey.py module of gevent you can see:

https://bitbucket.org/denis/gevent/src/f838056c793d/gevent/monkey.py#cl-128

```
def patch_time():
    """Replace :func:`time.sleep` with :func:`gevent.sleep`."""
    from gevent.hub import sleep
    import time
    patch_item(time, 'sleep', sleep)
```

Take a look at the code from the gevent's repository for details.

Comment: Yup, just arrived at that code,too. And since @neutrinus imports sleep from time before importing async in case 1, he is going to miss out on that patch wherever he just uses sleep instead of time.sleep

Comment: Thanks for a full explanation. As it looks like problem with gevent patching... I've upgraded to gevent version 1.0 and it worked (they moved to libev instead of libevent). This version should be in pypi btw...