# Multiprocessing hanging with requests.get

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, multiprocessing, python-multiprocessing

I have been working with a very simple bit of code, but the behavior is very strange. I am trying to send a request to a webpage using `requests.get`, but if the request takes longer than a few seconds, I would like to kill the process. I am following the response from the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14920384/stop-code-after-time-period), but changing the function body to include the `request`. My code is below:

```
import multiprocessing as mp, requests
def get_page(_r):                   
  _rs = requests.get('https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/browse/drinks/cordials-juices-iced-teas/iced-teas').text
  _r.put(_rs)

q = mp.Queue() 
p = mp.Process(target=get_page, args=(q,))
p.start()
time.sleep(3)
p.terminate()
p.join()
try:
   result = q.get(False)
   print(result)
except:
   print('failed')
```

The code above simply hanges when running it. However, when I run

```
requests.get('https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/browse/drinks/cordials-juices-iced-teas/iced-teas').text
```

independently, a response is returned in under two seconds. Therefore, main code should print the page's HTML, however, it just stalls. Oddly, when I put an infinite loop in `get_page`:

```
def get_page(_r): 
  while True:
     pass
  _r.put('You will not see this')
```

the process is indeed terminated after three seconds. Therefore, I am certain the behavior has to do with `requests`. How could this be? I discovered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10438802/strange-problems-when-using-requests-and-multiprocessing), but I am not using `async`. Could the issue have to do with monkey patching, as I am using `requests` along with `time` and `multiprocessing`? Any suggestions or comments would be appreciated. Thank you!

I am using:

- Python 3.7.0
- `requests` 2.21.0

Edit: @Hitobat pointed out that a param `timeout` can be used instead with `requests`. This does indeed work, however, I would appreciate any other ideas pertaining to why the `requests` is failing with `multiprocessing`.

Comment: Have you considered using the timeout param for requests.get?

Comment: @Hitobat Thank you, that does indeed work. I had never heard of that parameter before :). If you would like to post that suggest as a complete answer, I can certainly upvote it, but I am curious to know from other users why the original attempt with `multiprocessing` failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have reproduced your scenario and I have to refute the mentioned supposition *"I am certain the behavior has to do with requests"*. 
`requests.get(...)` returns the response as expected.

Let see how the process goes with some debug points:

```
import multiprocessing as mp, requests
import time


def get_page(_r):
    _rs = requests.get('https://www.woolworths.com.au/shop/browse/drinks/cordials-juices-iced-teas/iced-teas').text
    print('--- response header', _rs[:17])
    _r.put(_rs)


q = mp.Queue()
p = mp.Process(target=get_page, args=(q,))
p.start()
time.sleep(3)
p.terminate()
p.join()

try:
    print('--- get data from queue of size', q.qsize())
    result = q.get(False)
    print(result)
except Exception as ex:
    print('failed', str(ex))
```

The output:

```
--- response header 
<!DOCTYPE html>
--- get data from queue of size 1
```

As we see the response is there and the process even advanced to `try` block statements but it hangs/stops at the statement `q.get()` when trying to extract data from the queue.
Therefore we may conclude that the queue is likely to be corrupted.
And we have a respective warning in `multiprocessing` library documentation ([`Pipes and Queues`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#pipes-and-queues) section):

> **Warning**
>
> If a process is killed using `Process.terminate()` or os.kill() while
>   it is trying to use a Queue, then the data in the queue is likely to
>   become corrupted. This may cause any other process to get an exception
>   when it tries to use the queue later on.

Looks like this is that kind of case.

---

***How can we handle this issue?***

A known workaround is using `mp.Manager().Queue()` (with intermediate *proxying* level) instead of `mp.Queue`:

```
...
q = mp.Manager().Queue()
p = mp.Process(target=get_page, args=(q,))
```